# how to set row height for all dynamically generated rows using grid-template-rows in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS Grid and using to design an invoice. In my code sample, I have `#itemscontent` element as `grid`. This section will have invoice items loaded from database and there can be `n` number of rows.

To mock that I have added 3 rows to the section. But the height value that I set in `grid-template-rows` is getting applied only to first row in grid. Remaining rows just split the remaining available space.

For 3 rows example,
`grid-template-rows: 2rem 2rem 2rem` works as expected but `grid-template-rows: 2rem` applies height only to first row.

Is there any property in CSS Grid which can use to specify `2rem` as height for all rows inside `#itemscontent` grid?

```css
body {
    margin: 1.25rem;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: grid;
    grid: "header" "main" "footer";
    grid-template-rows: 3rem calc(100% - 6rem) 3rem;
    height: 100vh;
}

header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: grid;
    grid: "caption";
    grid-template-rows: 3rem;
}

main {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
    grid: "invoicedetails" "invoiceitems" "invoiceinformation";
    grid-template-rows: 15% 70% 15%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}

#invoicedetails {
    grid-area: invoicedetails;
    display: grid;
    grid: "shop customer invoice";
    grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
}

#customer {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#invoiceitems {
    grid-area: invoiceitems;
    display: grid;
    grid: "itemsheader" "itemscontent" "itemsfooter";
    grid-template-rows: 5% 80% 15%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}

#itemsheader {
    grid-area: itemsheader;
    display: grid;
    grid: "sno description hsn price gst unit unitprice";
    grid-template-columns: 10% 40% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
    align-items: center;
}

#itemscontent {
    grid-area: itemscontent;
    display: grid;
    grid: "sno description hsn price gst unit unitprice";
    grid-template-rows: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 40% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    align-items: center;
}

#invoiceinformation {}

footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <header></header>
      <main>
         <section id="invoicedetails">
            <section id="shop"></section>
            <section id="customer"></section>
            <section id="invoice"></section>
         </section>
         <section id="invoiceitems">
            <section id="itemsheader">
               <div>S.No</div>
               <div>Description</div>
               <div>HSN/SAC</div>
               <div>Price</div>
               <div>GST (%)</div>
               <div>Unit</div>
               <div>Unit Price</div>
            </section>
            <section id="itemscontent">
               <div>1</div>
               <div>Pen</div>
               <div>-</div>
               <div>10</div>
               <div>0</div>
               <div>5</div>
               <div>50</div>
               <div>2</div>
               <div>Pencil</div>
               <div>-</div>
               <div>10</div>
               <div>0</div>
               <div>5</div>
               <div>50</div>
               <div>3</div>
               <div>SubTotal</div>
               <div></div>
               <div></div>
               <div></div>
               <div></div>
               <div>100</div>
            </section>
            <section id="itemsfooter"></section>
         </section>
         <section id="invoiceinformation"></section>
      </main>
      <footer></footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really should make use of the grid-specific unit `fr` instead of working with percentages: `grid-template-columns: 10% 40% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%` then is `grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr`, or using the `repeat()` function: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr repeat(5, 1fr)`. Same with `grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;`: `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`

Comment: thanks for teaching sir. I'll follow and practice using `fr` instead of `%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS has you covered:

```
#itemscontent { grid-auto-rows: 2rem; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows

You can then remove the `grid-template-rows` definition for that element.

Comment: I need to include both `grid-template-rows: 2rem;` and `grid-auto-rows: 2rem;`? If I add only `grid-auto-rows: 2rem;` this just applies the size to last two rows leaving the first one

Comment: @fingers10 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows#examples does not specify `grid-template-rows`, neither does the interactive example at the top of the page.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry I made a typo in question its not `#invoiceitems` its `#itemscontent`. I'll fix this in question.

Comment: Then you have other problems in your current grid which I don't have the time to analyze right now. I answered your question on how to specify a height for dynamic rows of unknown number. Would you not agree the answer is correct?